# Bind images in razor view to <img src> that are in loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Right now the only thing i want to know is how to bind the Image to the "img src" in razor view.I have searched the other questions but did not find the answer for images in loop.The current way written down does not work."~/Images/" is the folder where the uploaded images are.

```
@model List<propertyMgmt.Models.Property>
    <div id="propertyList">
          <label>Select properties to be Featured:</label><br />
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>
                @Html.Label("Property Description")
              </th>
              <th>
                @Html.Label("Property Cost")
              </th>
              <th>
                @Html.Label("Property Image")
              </th>
              <th>
                @Html.Label("Featured??")
              </th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
            {
            <tr>
              <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PropertyDescription)
              </td>
              <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PropertyCost)
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="~/Images/@(m=>m[i].PropertyImage)" />
              </td>
              <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsFeatured, new { 
                @onclick = "propertyCheckBoxSelect(this)" })
              </td>
            </tr>
            }
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: `@Model[i].PropertyImage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this.

```
<img src="~/Images/@(Model[i].PropertyImage)" />
```

Comment: Thank You Nitesh :)